# Install npm and gulp in docker4drupal

Tags: docker, npm, gulp, drupal-8, gulp-sass

I am working on an existing project that was built by [Droopler](https://github.com/droptica/droopler_project) distribution and [docker4drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal). As per [Droopler](https://github.com/droptica/droopler_project) distribution documentation, it requires **npm and gulp to compiled sass** easily and [docker4drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal) don't have it by default.

I tried to install in the container by `sudo apt-get install npm` and it says:

> sudo: apt-get: command not found

Is there any way to install npm and gulp in [docker4drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal) for my existing project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to install npm & gulp, access php container and install those.

access php container `docker-compose exec php bash`
install npm `sudo apk update && sudo apk add npm`
install gulp globally `sudo npm install -g gulp`

This is how I do it, maybe there is a better way.

Reference: [Install npm and gulp](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal/issues/457)